# Google sign-in not working (is image button reason?)

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-signin, google-one-tap

Problem is that last week Google Sign-in button worked, but i deleted whole project and started all over again.

Only thing in code what i changed was that i used <ImageButton> instead of <Button>. Can that be the reason or is there something else? When i debug project with my own device via USB, it doesn't even make "click" noise when ImageButton is clicked.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Askola"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".feature.homepage.MainActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".feature.auth.LoginActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

login_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/wine"
    tools:context=".feature.auth.LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/askolaimg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/askolanega"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_width="273dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/wine"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btnTxt"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/google_sign"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/askolaimg"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.556" />
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SignInClient oneTapClient;
    BeginSignInRequest signInRequest;
    ImageButton button;

    private static final int REQ_ONE_TAP = 2;  // Can be any integer unique to the Activity.
    private boolean showOneTapUI = true;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        button = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this);
        signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
                .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                        .setSupported(true)
                        // Your server's client ID, not your Android client ID.
                        .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.web_client_id))
                        // Only show accounts previously used to sign in.
                        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
                        .build())
                // Automatically sign in when exactly one credential is retrieved.
                .build();
        ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> activityResultLauncher =
                registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                                    try {
                                        SignInCredential credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(result.getData());
                                        String idToken = credential.getGoogleIdToken();
                                        if (idToken !=  null) {
                                            String email = credential.getId();
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email: "+email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } catch (ApiException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<BeginSignInResult>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(BeginSignInResult result) {
                                                IntentSenderRequest intentSenderRequest =
                                                        new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender()).build();
                                                activityResultLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest);
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .addOnFailureListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                // No Google Accounts found. Just continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                                                Log.d("TAG", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        });
    }
}
```

Tried to set intent filters .LAUNCHER and .DEFAULT, android.intent.action.(different commands). Thank you, appreciate already!

Comment: It would be better if we could narrow down the scope of the problem. For now, it seems that there are 2 changes from "when it worked". 1. You deleted the whole project and started over, 2. You changed the button to an ImageButton. My suggestion is, if you can change the button back to a normal `Button`, can you try that and determine if the `Button` is the real source of the trouble?

Comment: A. If the `ImageButton` was the source of the problem: I would just use the `Button` class with a drawable background, or just an ImageView with onPressed state (using state selectors). It's not elegant, but it looks like a imageButton and behaves like a imageButton so ..

Comment: B. If the `ImageButton` was not the source of the problem: look at the config of your project and find the real culprit, and focus on that. You may be looking for an answer to a non-existing problem.

Comment: It seems you set your button's onClickListener within the ActivityResultLauncher? Maybe try setting the on click listener right after you declare the button through `findViewById()`. ImageButton should work and should _not_ be the issue, we also use an ImageButton in our app for Google SSO. You can easily debug this by setting a breakpoint in the button's onClickListener and seeing if it gets called. If not, it's probably the issue mentioned before of declaring the onClickListener in the wrong place

Comment: Hi guys, if you even read it anymore. Finally, i might have find the problem. Everytime when i edit .xml file afterwards, i found that google one tap didnt anymore recognize buttons when clicked. Now it has worked one week... Odd.

Comment: And its gone again. This time i dont even touch the project, it goes off workin itself. What could be the answer?